# Unable to change OpenGL version on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm using FreeGLUT and I would like to use OpenGL 3.2. I'm on MacBook Pro (15", Early 2015) Mojave 10.14.3 which according to Apple documentation supports OpenGL up to 4.1. I have downloaded freeglut with brew. However no matter what I put into *glutInitContextVersion*, the **version does not change**. No matter what I do, the OpenGL version stays 2.1.

> Intel Iris Pro OpenGL Engine, 2.1 INTEL-12.4.7

The used code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

using namespace std;

void displayFunc() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(3,2);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 272);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");

    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);

    // Print the OpenGL version
    std::printf("%s\n%s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER), glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

My cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(AVT7)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa")

include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/3.0.0/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/freeglut/3.0.0/lib)

add_executable(AVT7 hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(AVT7 glut)
```

How can I get this working? I am aware that there might be problem by Apple not supporting OpenGL any more, however it should still work (especially with FreeGLUT).

Comment: Which GPU does your notebook have? If you have an additional AMD card (with automatic GPU switching), make sure that the application starts on the right GPU.

Comment: @BDL I have the version of MacBook without the dedicated GPU, so it's Intel Iris 5200 Pro.

Comment: Why do you want a Core Profile if you use old functions like `glMatrixMode`?

Comment: @Ripi2 This is just some working code, I want to use the newer functions in GL3.